# Chain jumps off when jumping

Tags: chain

My chain jumps off front chainring or changes gears in the rear when I jump over stuff. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes there is, but we will need a bit more information.  How many gears does the bike have, in the front and also in the back?

Comment: VTC you were asked for more information 3 hours ago and have been back on  line.

Comment: How worn is the chain and cassette?  How old is the bike generally?    How high is the chain tension from the derailleur.   How aggressive are your jumps?

Comment: In what context are we talking about jumping? Tricks on a BMX where it's the whole point of getting on the bike? Aggressive mountainbike riding? The occasional pothole on a road bike?

Answer (score 2):

John Allen [has an article](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chain-drop.html#why) on some common reasons why chains drop, which I think is worth reading. Wrong chain size, bad derailleur adjustment, insufficient derailleur capacity, chainring damage, etc.  are some reasons this could occur.

There are clutch rear derailleurs (common in mountain biking) which try to keep the chain taut-er when going over rough ground, where a regular derailleur might move in a way to reduce chain tension and lead to dropped chains. But rough handling on any bike increases the likelihood of dropped chains or things switching up on you.

Shimano calls their clutch rear derailleurs "Shadow" and SRAM calls them "Type 2".

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance your chain is too long. As a rule of thumb, when you're in your two biggest coggs (front & back), your rear derailleur arm should nearly fully extended.

There are some good tutorial videos out there that explain how to get the right chain length(http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing).

Comment: The chain could be too long, too old or the tensioning spring(s) of the RD too weak.